# Question regarding Adiabatic Process

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

In an adiabatic process, that is a process in which mathematically $dQ=0$,
$PV^γ=\text{constant}$.

Now my question is that do we have a value for this constant? This is because just like for isothermal process we have $PV=\text{constant}=RT$ ($T$ is constant)
I understand that here $PV^γ$ is not a function of temperature, as the temperature is not constant, but do we have a value for this constant?

Comment: This constant will depend on your physical system, so that you have to measure $P$ and $V$ in order to compute $PV^\gamma$ explicitly.

Comment: For ideal gases, $\gamma$ is the ratio $c_p/c_V$ of specific heats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In an adiabatic process, that is a process in which mathematically
> $dQ=0$,  $PV^γ=\text{constant}$.

First of all, the equation only applies to an ideal gas undergoing a reversible adiabatic process. Thus, applying the ideal gas law, the equation can also be written as $TV^{γ-1}=\text{constant}$

> Now my question is that do we have a value for this constant?

The value will vary depending on the pressure, volume, and adiabatic index of the particular system. The chief usefulness of the equation is that the value of the left side of the equation is the same for every equilibrium state along the process path. That is, for any two equilibrium states

$$P_{1}V_{1}^{\gamma}= P_{2}V_{2}^{\gamma}$$

or, alternatively

$$T_{1}V_{1}^{\gamma-1}= T_{2}V_{2}^{\gamma-1}$$

The same applies to the reversible isothermal process, that is for any two equilibrium states

$$P_{1}V_{1}=P_{2}V_{2}$$

Since both process involve an ideal gas, the ideal gas law applies to both processes.

$$PV=nRT$$

from which, where $nR$ = constant,

$$\frac{P_{1}V_{1}}{T_{1}}=\frac{P_{2}V_{2}}{T_{2}}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, as the constant depends on the pressure, volume and adiabatic index, do we have a mathematical relation for it

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya I'm not sure I understand your question. The relationship IS the equation $PV^{\gamma}$= constant. If I have 2 liters of air with an adiabatic index of 1.4 at 1 atmosphere pressure the constant is 2.63 L-Atm. If its 2 Atm pressure the constant is 5.26 L-Atm. If its 2 L of helium  with an index of 1.667 at 1 Atm the constant is 3.18 L-Atm, etc, etc.,

Comment: Thanks! I have understood my mistake.

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya Glad it helped!

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya By the way, in my last comments I inadvertently omitted the power in the units for the constant. E.g., $PV^\gamma$ = 2.63 L-atm should have been $=2.63 L^{1.4}$-atm, etc.